# Presenting proxy at a UML component diagram

Tags: uml, component-diagram

What would be the best way for describing an architecture consisting of a proxy, a client and a server (Web, SMTP, IMAP etc) on a UML component diagram?

What kinds of connectors should be used between the components and is there is a way for showing that though there is the proxy between the client and the server, the client still addresses the server and is not really interested in the proxy (this is especially relevant if the proxy is transparent)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to show the proxy is to use stereotypes, marking it with `<<proxy>>`. Everyone know what a proxy is so this is fairly failsafe.

Other than that, use standard UML associations between the classes. If you want you can also enclose the proxy and the client inside a square and the server in another square so the reader can understand that they are located in "different" places. While not standard UML, this will enhance the semantics of your diagram.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  What particularly interests me, is how to display that the client communicates with the server via an interface the server exposes (e.g. as a Web Service) and the proxy component is there, but doing really nothing interesting. Or maybe just leave out the proxy component from the diagram and draw a direct dependency between the client and the server's interface?

Comment: Of the existence of the proxy is not of importance, then not showing it is the right thing to do. And yes, creating a dependency from the client to the server interface is more correct than a dependency to the proxy, so that is what I would do. And if you liked the answer upvote it or mark it as correct :-)

Comment: Thanks again. As the other answer also suggested, I just left proxy out of the component diagram.

Answer (score 1):

A Proxy is an abstraction made up of (at least) two parts, the device and the software.  I agree that a proxy stereotype would be useful but I would apply it to the node and the component on a deployment diagram.  Connect the **devices** at the physical network level; **nodes** at the logical network level (HTTP/SMTP/etc) and components at the exposed interface level.